# how to authenticate neo4j database with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, neo4j

I configured neo4j database and added it to username and password.
when I run using localhost:7474 it working with authentication.
but I add username and password to config file in Laravel it doesn't working.

This is my neo4j configuration.

```
'neo4j' => array(
  'transport' => 'curl',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '7474',
  'debug' => true,
  'proxy_dir' => '/tmp',
  'cache_prefix' => 'neo4j',
  'meta_data_cache' => 'array',
  'annotation_reader' => null,
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'pathfinder_algorithm' => null,
  'pathfinder_maxdepth' => null
)
```

Comment: Which library do you use for the connection with Laravel ? 
And can you paste a log of your http connection headers to the DB ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this Neo4j package for Laravel: https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent